# What items can you smartcast with?

Tags: league-of-legends

It turns out you can't smartcast [Hextech Gunblade's active ability](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Hextech_Gunblade) after the Hecarim Patch. To clarify, you can set it to smartcast, but you'll still have to activate the ability, then click on a target, rather than activate the ability, and move your cursor over a target.

Are there any items with active abilities that can no longer be smartcast? Or is this just a bug?

Comment: I didn't even know you could smartcast item abilities XD

Comment: If you go to "Keybindings" and scroll down to "Item Inventory," you'll see six options called "Smart Cast Item 1-6."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to smartcast all items with an active ability (including wards).

As Andrew already explained, you can go into the "Kebybinding," go to the category "Item Inventory," and from there you can set "Smart Cast Items 1-6" to your preferred key (I would suggest taking the numbers 1-6).

List of Items that currently have an active targeting ability (excluding consumables):

- Bilgewater Cutlass
- Hextech Gunblade
- Deathfire Grasp
- Wriggle's Lantern
- Executioner's Calling
- Hextech Sweeper (Dominion only)

Note: All items with an active ability that don't require you to choose a target (e.g. Runduin's Omen) are used by simply pressing the corresponding button to the item slot (no matter if you use Item smart casts or not).

Comment: After reading a couple forum posts, it seems like this is more of a bug that happened after the Hecarim patch. To fix it, you can turn off the range indicators. Otherwise, you're completely correct Patrick.